# Remove Soap Envelope from the $body before using Send mediator in WSO2

Tags: json, wso2

My API is receiving a XML with a field that repeats itself a couple of times, looking like this:

```xml
<Root>
  <Element>
    <Request>username=username&password=password&field3=field3&field4=field4</Request>
    <Request>username=username&password=password&field3=field3&field4=field4</Request>
  </Element>
</Root>
```

Using an `IterateMediator` I am extracting those Request fields and make separate calls with each of them to an URL, with the help of an `AggregatorMediator` and a`SendMediator`.

The API I'm calling will only accept only one line at a time, along with the following metadata:

```
HTTP method: POST    
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded    
Payload: username=username&password=password&field3=field3&field4=field4
```

The problem is that, although I extract the payload properly from the `IterateMediator`, the value of the `$body` before reaching the SendMediator is surrounded with Soap Envelope tags. I've tried using a `PayloadFactoryMediator` to change the value of the `$body`, but I can only make it xml or json, and not text/plain.

Do you have any idea how can I make the body something else than xml or json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to force text/plain in WSO2 call to an endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973853/how-to-force-text-plain-in-wso2-call-to-an-endpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your sequence?

"..but I can only make it xml or json, and not text/plain.."

Did you try media-type="text" ?

```
<payloadFactory media-type="text" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <format>$1</format>
</payloadFactory>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution. Apparently, the fault is in my current version of  Eclipse plugin which doesn't allow media-type="text".

Comment: OK, If it is the solution, could you mark it as a correct answer?